# issue with setting focus not working

Tags: c#, focus, groupbox

I have a screen where the user enters in to a text box a name of a location. then click on a button to open a group box that has three textboxes Firstname, lastname and PW. I am trying to set the focus to the firstname text box when the user clicks the button to make the group box visible (on the main form). but it will not set the focus (txtbxnameFirst.focus();)

Comment: mention code snap..

Comment: I assume you are looking for a [tag:C#] solution and either using [tag:winforms] or [tag:wpf]?

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't work the way you hinted.  Post the code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: If my answer is not what you were looking for than it would be helpfull if you left a comment or add details to your question by editing / updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Requirement

I understood the following:

- user writes text into `locationTextBox` and clicks the button `locationSaveButton`
- after clicking the button a [`GroupBoxControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.groupbox?view=netframework-4.7) should be set to visible and the `firstNameTextBox` shall receive the focus

#### The code

The button that is clicked after entereing the location `locationButton` has a  Click Event with this code

```
private void locationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get value from textbox location
    string location = locationTextBox.Text;
    // make the groupBox visible
    groupBox1.Visible = true;
    // set the focus to the textbox for the firstname
    firstNameTextBox.Focus();           
}
```

#### Simple Demo with windows forms

This how the application looks before clicking the button

[image: Windows Forms]

After clicking it the groubBox is set to visible and the other TextBoxes are visible and the focus is set to the `firstNameTextBox`

[image]